# MS Edge losing cookies

Tags: cookies, browser

Have no idea how to describe the problem, therefore here is all the details:

THE PROBLEM: although cookies lifetime is set to max days, I'm observing from time to that MS Edge (up-to-date version according Win 11 updates) lose them.

WHERE HAPPENS:

- custom made CMS controlling 4 webshops on 4 domains. All the same but languages.
- 3 cookies in use: sessions, cookiebanner, and one setcookie() I'm using for my purposes, simply none or =1.

3 of 4 websites keeps their cookies for a long time (at the moment since 2022) but site (4) from time to time lost basket and shows the cookiemanner again. The only thing is different - at sites (1)...(3) I'm keeping with item in a basket just to control that everything works fine and may be once a month I use one of them to make an order if customer asked me to do it instead of him. But the site (4) I'm using for this purpose much more often. And IT SEEMS that the reason of loosing cookies is exactly this actions, but as it showed by sites (1)...(3) not every order completing causes that cookie death.

The session_destroy() is in php, calling once if order is completd. But AFAIK it mustn't touch any cookie and the only way to delete it is set it expiration date in a past. But even if session_destroy() can somehow delete the session cookie, it couldn't kill other two. But I've checked - the time of death are exactly the same at all 3 cookies.

And the thing is that at the same time as this heppens, couple of other sites logout me. Completely away sites, not mine.

IT LOOKS LIKE: MS Edge erasing SOME cookie containers, but what is the reason and why exactly that websites (again, my sites (1)...(3) are with 2022'th cookies till now)?

ALSO: at Mozilla Firefox all (1)...(4) has cookies dated 2022, and I'm also making test orders on (4) there but not often, but since 2022 I've made for sure more than at MS Edge during a week.

May be somebody meet the same behavior? Tried to google this problem, but found nothing even not nearby...

This part of code is definatelly prior to session_start(), but this cookie is also affected...

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sessions/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (empty($_COOKIE['spath'])) {
    setcookie('spath', '1', time() + (1 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        if (!is_bool(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'bot')) || !is_bool(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'spider')) || !is_bool(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Slurp')) || !is_bool(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'crawler')) || !is_bool(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Uptime')) || !is_bool(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebook')) || !is_dir($path)) {
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sessions/bots';
        }
    }
}
ini_set('session.save_path', $path);
```